# Asynchronous Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, controller

Do you have anything more expressive on Asynchronous Controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Cheers
:)

Comment: I am looking for an elaborative sample explaining the async controllers used in MVC2?

Comment: Could you reword your question, and reference some Googled examples, and say how they are not "expressive " enough so we understand what part of Asynchronous Controllers you haven't yet groked

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this msdn article it has a sample example as well

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=VS.98).aspx